# Write positive and negative numbers between 3 text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

A file named data.txt contains an unknown number of lines, each consisting of a single integer. Write some code that creates two files, dataplus.txt and dataminus.txt, and copies all the lines of data1.txt that have positive integers to dataplus.txt, and all the lines of data1.txt that have negative integers to dataminus.txt. Zeros are not copied anywhere.

This code is what I have so far. It runs into an execution error and doesn't write anything to the text files.

```
minus = open('dataminus.txt', 'a')
plus = open('dataplus.txt', 'a')
source = open('data.txt', 'r')
sor = source.readline()
while sor != '':
    x = int(sor)
    if (x > 0):
        plus.write(x)
    elif (x < 0):
        minus.write(x)
    sor = source.readline()
source.close()
minus.close()
plus.close()
```

Comment: Make sure you cast `x` back to `str` before calling `write()`

Comment: If you want to _w_rite to a file, use `'w'` flag.

Comment: according to your question, shouldn't you write to `dataminus.txt` and `dataplus.txt`and open them in `w` mode? Also, data.txt should be opened in read(`r`) mode?

Comment: always show full `Traceback` (error message) in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Had to convert it to a string and write each number to a new line:

```
minus = open('dataminus.txt', 'a')
plus = open('dataplus.txt', 'a')
source = open('data.txt', 'r')
sor = source.readline()
while sor != '':
    x = int(sor)
    if (x > 0):
        plus.write(str(x)+'\n')
    elif (x < 0):
        minus.write(str(x)+'\n')
    sor = source.readline()
source.close()
minus.close()
plus.close()
```

Comment: @Matthew Barlow, that would be true if the code was writing the sor string back into the destination files. Instead this code seems to write str(x), with x being int(sor). The conversion to int and back should strip any newline characters from the string. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As someone already said in a comment, you just need to convert x back to a str, which is what the runtime error must've said (`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int`

```
minus = open('dataminus.txt', 'a')
plus = open('dataplus.txt', 'a')
source = open('data.txt', 'r')
sor = source.readline()
while sor != '':
    x = int(sor)
    if (x > 0):
        plus.write(str(x)+'\n')
    elif (x < 0):
        minus.write(str(x)+'\n')
    sor = source.readline()
source.close()
minus.close()
plus.close()
```

The other issue you would've noticed is the need to add a newline after every number.